# SSH port forwarding works only with Source port Any

Tags: networking, router, ssh, port-forwarding

I am trying to setup port forwarding for SSH so I could connect to my raspberry pi from another network.

I have these pages in my router (DRG-A125G):
[image]
[image]

It works only if I specify Source port Any (what it means?) and Destination port 22. If I set both to 22 or one to 12386 and another to 22 I can't connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source port is the port that the SSH client bind in order to connect to the SSH server located on the raspberry on port 22.

The client port is needed because the response packets (from SSH server to SSH client) must have a destination on the network (SSH client IP address and the port where SSH client process is listening).

The client usually choose a random-free-unprivileged port (> 1024) on every connection so if you choose a specific source port the port forwarding will not work (unless your SSH client is VERY lucky to choose this specific port).

So in order to reach SSH server you must choose the option "Any Port" as source.

Please note that choose "any port" is not a security threat by itself, instead you should consider to do some security fix in order to protect yourself from unauthorized access, like:

- Choose a good password or, better, allow only login through SSH keys
- Limit the source IP address to a specific trusted range (if possible)
- Limit the max failed login attempt with something like [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)
- Don't expose SSH directly but through a VPN service like [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/)

Comment: hm. Then why most of the tutorials suggest to set both ports to 22?
Such as http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/6757/how-to-use-ssh-out-of-home-network and http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Pirelli/DRG-A125G/SSH.htm

Comment: Every ADSL router has a different interface for port forwarding configuration and different labels for same input fields trying to "simplify" the things... Probably the "Source port" mean "external port" the port that should be opened internet-side and forwarded to the raspberry. If my theory is correct (and should be, because on portforward.com is compiled as 22) you must put 22 as source port too or, if you want, you can put another port (12345) but you must specify the not-standard port in you connection command `ssh -p 12345 <your public IP>`. Can you try and let me know if it works?

Comment: Yes, as I said earlier: both 22 or Source 22 Destination 12386 or vice versa (of course also specifying it in the client) — can't connect, Source Any Destination 22 — works.

Comment: Wait, let me summarize, source any - Destination 22 --> works, source 22 - destination 22 works, source 12345 destination 22 --> doesn't works, source 22 destination 12345 --> doesn't works, correct? (I'm asking that because in original question I understand that 22-22 doesn't work too...) When it doesn't works what error did you get? Connection refused? A timeout?

Comment: No, Source 22 Destination 22 doesn't work too. Connection timeout in all three cases.

Comment: Ok, looking again I see that on the guide this router security option is set to minimal http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Pirelli/DRG-A125G/DRG-A125G3.jpg can you check that you don't have for example "typical"  selected? And, last resource, have you already tried to reboot the router? Sometimes changes stay pending or stuck on low end devices...

Comment: Changed to minimal, now it says connection refused instead of timeout.

Comment: That's good, it's mean that is not a firewall that silently drop the connection, have you already tried all ports combinations?

Comment: Yes, I tried, works only with Any.
Anyway I will probably setup VPN instead of forwarding SSH and other services directly. But as I understand I would still need to add port forwarding for OpenVPN ports in the same way, so the question is still relevant.

Comment: I'm begin to think that the portforward.com instructions are wrong... looking on other sites/screenshots I founded an Advanced > Protocols screeshot [http://i.imgur.com/FB6gAJw.png] where I can see some standards services pre-configured (default protocols that you can see and select "in Add port forwarding rule" page), look at HTTP (a TCP service, as SSH), the configuration is Any -> 80. Can you check the Advanced -> Protocolspage on your router? If default services are configured with source port = Any I'm starting to think that my original answer was more correct than I think

Comment: Yes, I have the same page with Any. Also if pressed Advanced button it shows more rules, including SSH.

Comment: And is it work? How it's configured?

Comment: The same as I did when it worked: Any -> 22.

Comment: At this point I think that the "source port" is in fact the "remote port" and should always be "any" unless you have some specific reasons. For VPN is the same, but you must forward the correct port (for openVPN 1194 by default)